# Alphabetical Bubble sorting Array

Tags: c++, sorting

Given an input of the number of names, I am supposed to list them alphabetically using bubble sorting. However, I cannot seem to get my algorithm correct, as my output is given in some random order. My example input is

```
5 
Alice Hawking 
John Smith 
Stephen Hawking 
Alice Cooper 
Jean Smith
```

Code is

```
int main() {
    int number;
    char char1;
    char char2;
    int measure;
    int name1;
    int name2;
    int flag = 1;
    int count = 0, ter = 0;
    string tmp;

    cin >> number;

    string list[number+1][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        cin >> list[i][0] >> list[i][1];
    }

    // sorting first names
    for (int k = 0; k <= number; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number - 1; i++) {
            // j cannot go beyond the length of the smallest first name
            // so measure will be the measure of the smallest first name
            if (list[i][0].size() < list[i+1][0].size()) {
                measure = list[i][0].size();
            } else {
                measure = list[i+1][0].size();
            }

            // convert the each letter of the string by converting 
            // string to char to int
            // flag is to indicate if the two comparisons are not the same
            // so that the if loop does not continue 
            for (int j = 0; flag && j < measure; j++) {
                char1 = list[i][0].at(j);
                char2 = list[i+1][0].at(j);
                name1 = (int)char1;
                name2 = (int)char2;
                if (name1 > name2) {
                    tmp = list[i][0];
                    list[i][0] = list[i+1][0];
                    list[i+1][0] = tmp;
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    // sorting last names
    for (int k = 0; k <= number; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number - 1; i++) {
            // j cannot go beyond the length of the smallest last name
            // so measure will be the measure of the smallest last name
            if (list[i][1].size() < list[i+1][1].size()) {
                measure = list[i][0].size();
            } else {
                measure = list[i+1][0].size();
            }

            for (int j = 0; flag && j < measure; j++) {
                char1 = list[i][1].at(j);
                char2 = list[i+1][1].at(j);
                name1 = (int)char1;
                name2 = (int)char2;
                if (name1 > name2) {
                    tmp = list[i][1];
                    list[i][1] = list[i+1][1];
                    list[i+1][1] = tmp;
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
            flag = 1;
        }
    }


    for (int t = 0; t < number; t++) {
        cout << list[t][0] << " " << list[t][1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may split into subfunctions as `min`, `swap`, `string_compare`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to look at.

1 Comparing strings.

Is there any reason you don't just use `string` comparison to compare the names? The entire code from `// j cannot go` to `flag=` (except for the swap) could be replaced by

```
if (list[i][0] > list[i+1][0])
```

2 Comparing first and last in two loops.

It would be much better to check the last name and the first name in the same loop. Something like:

```
if (list[i][0] > list[i+1][0] || (list[i][0] == list[i+1][0] && list[i][1] > list[i+1][1]) {
}
```

Note: change the `0` and `1` if you want to sort by last name then first name.

3 Swapping

At the moment you are swapping first names independently of last names. This will lead to your names being jumbled up. Swap them both at the same time.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know that string comparisons worked like that. Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of trouble.